# Update Notification with a Button click

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just a newbie of Android, while I programming I had the problem that is about the Notification.

I need your help to process updating notification. 
The context of this like when you are playing the game and you had a notification about another game (the second game is running in the background). Then you have a new notification of the second game which has the same `ID` of the previous notification.

This is my declaration:
I used `NotificationManager`class to create a Notification.

```
private NotificationManager manager;
private int notiId = 6789; // Each notification will be managed by an ID
private int numMsg = 0;
```

This is the function `clickToSend` button:

```
public void clickToSend(View view) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    // Setting Notification Properties
    builder.setContentTitle("New Message");
    builder.setContentText("Notification Demo: Message has received");
    builder.setTicker("Message Alert");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_unread);
    builder.setNumber(++numMsg);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationDetailActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stack = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stack.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stack.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(notiId, builder.build());
}
```

I think code of function `clickToUpdate` that will process like the `clickToSend` function.

Thanks for your help!

My language is not good. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: whats the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I thought clearly about my problem and that is How to get the notification ID and I will call function `clickToSend` again